# Android: How to mimic canvas.concat(Matrix)?

Tags: android

I am concatenating matrices to a Canvas, but later I would like to be able to perform canvas.getClipBounds() to find the current clip of the Canvas.  However, canvas.getClipBounds() returns a Rect (as opposed to a RectF), the imprecision of which I believe is causing me issues.

So, I intend to maintain my own RectF and transform it as the Canvas gets transformed, so that in the end it should be similar to the value returned by canvas.getClipBounds(), but in float precision.

However, I do not understand how canvas.concat(Matrix) effects the Canvas' clip, because my attempts to mimic the concatenation are going very poorly.  Below is some code that I'm trying, with the values as comments.  I would expect one of the temp RectFs to have a similar value as `m_Canvas.getClipBounds.toString()` does after concatenation, but I'm not even close. Any suggestions?

```
 protected void processConcatMatrix(Matrix m)
     {
        //m.toString() == Matrix{[1103.398, -134.48357, 23.99026][174.76108, 849.0959, -159.39447][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}
        //m_Canvas.getMatrix().toString() == Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, -1.0, 706.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}
        //m_Canvas.getClipBounds.toString() == Rect(0, 0 - 1024, 706)
        m_Canvas.concat(m);
         //m_Canvas.getClipBounds().toString() = Rect(0, 0 - 1, 1);
        //m_Canvas.getMatrix().toString == Matrix{[1103.398, -134.48357, 23.99026][-174.76108, -849.0959, 865.3945][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

        RectF temp = new RectF(0, 0 - 1024, 706);
        Matrix m1 = new Matrix(m);
        m1.mapRect(temp);
        //temp.toString() == RectF(-94921.41, -159.39447, 1129903.5, 778257.6)

        //not sure if I should use the parameter matrix, or the canvas matrix after concatentation.  let's try with both


        RectF temp2 = new RectF(0, 0 - 1024, 706);
        Matrix m2 = new Matrix(m_Canvas.getMatrix());
        m2.mapRect(temp2);
        //temp2.toString() == RectF(-94921.41, -777551.6, 1129903.5, 865.3945)

        //maybe I'm supposed to invert the matrices???

        RectF temp3 = new RectF(0, 0 - 1024, 706);
        Matrix m3 = new Matrix(m);
        m3.invert(m3);
        m3.mapRect(temp3);
        //temp3.toString() == RectF(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 706.0)

        //not sure if I should use the parameter matrix, or the canvas matrix after concatentation.  let's try with both

        RectF temp4 = new RectF(0, 0 - 1024, 706);
        Matrix m4 = new Matrix(m_Canvas.getMatrix());
        m4.invert(m4);
        m4.mapRect(temp4);
        //temp4.toString == RectF(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 706.0)


        //ok, none of these values resembled Rect(0, 0 - 1, 1).  Clearly I am doing something wrong...
  }
```

Comment: Why not just take the 'final' matrix of the Canvas (the one used when drawing) and map the rect with it? `m_Canvas.getMatrix().mapRect(transformedRect, originalRect)`

Comment: I am also noticing that your `RectF` defenition is using only three parameters, is the `0-1024` supposed to be `0,1024`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `Matrix` variable to keep track of concats to the canvas if want to truly mimic `canvas.concatMatrix(Matrix);`.

```
    m_Canvas.concat(m);
    m_Matrix.preConcat(m); // Did you forget this?

    RectF temp = new RectF(0, 0, 1024, 706);
    Matrix m1 = new Matrix(m_Matrix);
    m1.mapRect(temp);
    //temp.toString() == RectF(-94921.41, -777551.6, 1129903.5, 865.3945)

    RectF temp2 = new RectF(0, 0, 1024, 706);
    Matrix m2 = new Matrix(m_Canvas.getMatrix());
    m2.mapRect(temp2);
    //temp2.toString() == RectF(-94921.41, -777551.6, 1129903.5, 865.3945) // same as temp
```